# Why are my custom headers giving an "Adapter operation failed" error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ember.js, ember-data

Aloha! Today, I'm trying to **add custom headers to each request to my backend.**

Playing with my `DS.RESTAdapter`, I already tried:

- The 3 `headers:` solutions suggested **[in the official guide](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_headers-customization)**.
- The 2 `ajax:` approaches proposed **[around there](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/passing-the-querystring-in-the-headers-of-a-rest-call/8270)**.
- And 2 jQuery workarounds (based on `$.ajaxPrefilter` and `$.ajaxSetup`) that I found **[there](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/passing-header-information-to-rest-get-request-using-restadapter/4220/17)**.

Until now, my only result was this very obscure **"Adapter operation failed"** error:

```
{
  details: "",
  status: 0,
  title: "The backend responded with an error"
}
```

I know that:

- My backend behaves well and returns a 200 status (I tested sending the request via cURL).
- **Strangely, removing my adapter's `host` setting allows the request to be sent**, but obviously at the wrong URL.
- My problem is not a CSP issue as I'm currently running both backend & frontend locally.

According to my debugging and to my *Network Inspector* tab, the AJAX request is just never sent ([`XHR.readyStatus`](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp) is stuck at 0).

**Has somebody already faced this?**
Any help would be really lovely!

- Ember `1.13.11`
- Ember Data `1.13.15`
- jQuery `1.11.3`

---

### EDIT: Magic minimal app reproducing the bug is [out here](https://github.com/imbrou/ember-data-headers-demo/)!

Hope you'll enjoy it! And because I love you so much, I also offered a demo API endpoint on my server. Details in the FM!

**BONUS!** Do you know what is the coolest thing to put in a clipboard?
`git clone https://github.com/imbrou/ember-data-headers-demo.git`

Yeeeeeeha! (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved !**

My backend was not sending the correct CORS headers.

The tricky thing is that for an unknown reason, my version of Firefox (Developer Edition...) didn't display the failing OPTIONS request in my Network Inspector at the point of my debugging. I thus had no debugging information at all there.

**I could only observe the failing preflight using... Wireshark !**

It may have been a bug solved in a Christmas update, as I can't reproduce it today. Too bad...

Anyway, in desperation, I linked 3 screenshots:

1. [No-preflight example](http://broubrou.olympe.in/util/stack/headers-demo/screenshots/1.png): no backend security (no "authorization" token).
2. [Working example](http://broubrou.olympe.in/util/stack/headers-demo/screenshots/2.png): the "authorization" header is requested by client, and allowed by server in the response during the preflight.
3. [Failing example](http://broubrou.olympe.in/util/stack/headers-demo/screenshots/3.png): the "authorization" header is requested by the client, BUT not allowed by the server.

Hope it helps, thanks @Vítor for your support !

Answer (score 1):

Usually **"Adapter operation failed"** error occurs because your application is having problems connecting to the *backend*, usually `DS.RESTAdapter` is not correctly setup, make sure your `host` and `namespace` are correct.

Example:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://193.137.170.210:8080',
    namespace: '/api'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I double-checked my `RESTadapter`'s configuration and everything works perfectly (with no headers) if I remove the `headers:` hook. Is there another parameter I may have forgotten? I guess I have set `host` and `namespace` correctly.